# Combine TikZ animation with ggplot animation

Tags: r, animation, markdown, sweave, tikz

I'm trying to recreate [this animation](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Bode/BodeWhat.html##section15). What I want is to have the mechanical system in TikZ and the plot in R/ggplot. In the end I want to use all this in a presentation, ideally in a R markdown/sweave presentation.

Is this even possible?

What I have until now is the TikZ of the mechanical system:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
    \tikzstyle{blocksmall} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height = 0.25cm, minimum width = 0.25cm]
    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height = 1cm, minimum width = 2cm]
    \tikzstyle{spring} = [decorate, decoration = {zigzag, pre length = 0.3cm, post length = 0.3cm, segment length = 6}]
    \tikzstyle{ground} = [fill, pattern = north east lines, draw = none, minimum width = 0.75cm, minimum height = 0.3cm]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [blocksmall] (u) {$u$};
        \node [block, right of = u, node distance = 3cm] (m) {$m$};
        \node (ground) [ground, anchor = north, yshift = -0.25cm, xshift = 0cm, minimum width = 7cm] at (m.south) {};
        \draw (ground.north east) -- (ground.north west);
        \draw (m.south west) ++ (0.4cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm)  (m.south east) ++ (-0.4cm,-0.125cm) circle (0.125cm);
        \draw [spring] (u) -- node[auto, yshift = 0.15cm] {$k$} (m);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 1:** I found that this animation is done with Raphael.js and the custom [linear.js](https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/12/abiele1/Linear/linear.js). Everything then is combined in [freq.html](https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/12/abiele1/Linear/examples/freq.html).

Answer (score 0):

it might be to late but just to mention one possible solution for the future:

In the current development version of TikZ there is a new animation library that can be used to produce animated SVGs[Documentation of the animations-library](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/doc/generic/pgf/text-en/pgfmanual-en-base-animations.tex?view=markup). Maybe this information could help you. I don't know how to use the tool and what it is able to, but I already saw a beamer presentation using this library for animated graphs. It seemed to work well.